# Reboot the server at a given date and time

Tags: windows, powershell, reboot, scheduled-tasks

I need to schedule a reboot of a server every other Saturday at 11 PM.

I need to get this automated and not have to run it manually.

I have tried `SCHTasks` but the client does not accept and needs a PowerShell script I think in order to achieve it so I can push it via RMM.

Any guidance or other starting points to get a scheduled and automated reboot of a server?

Comment: Push a PowerShell script that creates a scheduled task?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! We are not a free coding service but a community of people interested in computers that are willing to share their knowledge and experience. If you have already tried something please post it here, otherwise this question is likely to be closed due to lack of preliminary work by you.

Comment: I disagree with closing tbis question.  It is amenable to an answer, and I would imagine does not require any coding.

Comment: @davidgo I usually edit the question myself to make it more appropriate and on point to take out those "asking for a script" wording, then vote to re-open per this example edit I'll make. Let's go!!

Answer (score 0):

You have **two** options:

1. Create the task once on the server manually.`

   Go to the task scheduler. right click on the task scheduler library and choose create a task.

   1. In the general tab: Name it something like reboot or whatever you would like to call it. Check the "Run whether user is logged on or not".
   2. In the triggers tab: click "New" and choose your schedule.
   3. In the Action tab: click "New" --> Action = start a program --> in program/script type: Powershell.exe --> in Add Arguments field type: `shutdown -r -t 0`
2. Create a PowerShell script that can create a scheduled task for you.

   Follow this link to create your script: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/use-powershell-to-create-scheduled-tasks/